# Counting $x$ where $an < x \le (an+n)$ and lpf($x$) $ \ge \frac{n}{4}$ and $1 \le a \le n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Let lpf($x)$ be the [least prime factor](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastPrimeFactor.html) of $x$.

It seems to me that if:

- $1 \le a \le n$
- $n \ge 128$
- $an < x \le (an+n)$
- lpf($x$) $\ge \frac{n}{4}$

Then, for all $y$ where:

- $an < y \le (an+n)$
- $ y \ne x$

It follows that

- lpf($y$) $< \frac{n}{4}$

Here's my reasoning:

**Claim 1:** if $p \ge  \frac{n}{4}$, then $p^3 > n^2+n$

(1)  $\frac{n}{64} \ge 2$

(2)  $\frac{n^2}{64} \ge n + n > n + 1$

(3)  $p^3 \ge \frac{n^3}{64} > n^2 + n$

**Claim 2:** if $p,q$ are primes where $p > q$ and $\frac{n^2}{16} < pq < n^2$, then $p^2 - q^2 > n$

(1) $(i+2)^2 - i^2 = 4i+4$

(2) $p^2 - q^2 \ge 4\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)+4 > n$

**Claim 3**: if $an < y \le (an+n)$ and $y \ne x$, then lpf($y$) $< \frac{n}{4}$

(1) abs($x-y) < $ abs($an+n - an) = n$

(2) Assume that $n >$ lpf($y$) $\ge \frac{n}{4}$

(3) Let $p = $lpf($y$)

(4) $y = p^2$

> $p < y$ since $y > n > p$ and from Claim 1, $p^3 > y$

(5) By the same argument if $q = $lpf($x$), then $q^2 =x$

(6) But abs($x - y) =$ abs($p^2 - q^2) > n$ so the conclusion follows.

Is my reasoning correct?  Is there any mistake in my thinking?

---

Edit 1: I realized an oversight.

Let $q,p$ be primes $p>q$.  There is the possibility that $p=q+2$ which means that $pq - q^2 = 2q < n$.

So, the argument only applies to squares of distict primes but not to least prime factors.

Comment: Using sieving, there are those kind of formulas $\displaystyle\sum_{m \in (A,B], \ lpf(m) \ge k} 1 = \sum_{n, \ Lpf(n) < k} \mu(n)(\lfloor \frac{B}{n}\rfloor- \lfloor \frac{A}{n}\rfloor) = (B-A)\prod_{p < k} (1-\frac{1}{p})+ \mathcal{O}(...)$