# What is wrong with this effort to generalize Bertrand's Postulate using the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

The following argument is too elementary to be true but I am not clear where the error is.  I would appreciate it if you could call out what is logically wrong or provide a counter example to one claim in the argument.

Let $n \ge 128$ be an integer.

Let $1 \le a \le n$ be an integer.

Let lpf$(x)$ be the [least prime factor](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastPrimeFactor.html) of $x$.

Let $\frac{n}{4}\#$ be the [primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) for $\left\lfloor\frac{n}{4}\right\rfloor$.

**Claim:**  There is at least one prime between $an$ and $an+n$.

(1) Either lpf($x) \le \sqrt{x}$ or $x$ is a prime.

(2) There are at least $3$ integers $x$ where $an < x \le (an+n)$ and $\gcd(x,\frac{n}{4}\#)=1$.

The details for this argument are found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2315660/48606).

(3) There is at most $1$ integer $x$ where $an < x \le (an+n)$ and $n \ge $ lpf$(x) \ge \frac{n}{4}$

The details for this argument are found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2305098/48606).

(4)  So, at least $2$ integers $x$ where $an < x \le (an+n)$ have lpf$(x) > n$

(5)  But for $m < (n^2+n)$, if lpf$(m) > n$, then lpf$(m) > \sqrt{m}$ and $m$ is a prime.

(6)  It follows that at least one integer $x$ where $an < x < (an+n)$ is prime.

---

**Edit 1**:  Gerhard Paseman has pointed out a [problem](https://mathoverflow.net/q/271628/15915) with my assumption used in the [original argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2310414/are-there-always-at-least-3-integers-x-where-an-x-le-ann-and-gcdx) for step (2).

For this reason, I am now using this [argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2315660/48606) for step (2).

Comment: Interesting idea look at the number of primes between $an$ and $(a+1)n$ for $a=1,\cdots ,n$ ... From the Betrand postulate to the (nearly) Legendre conjecture ... Thanks for idea ! ... Oh, no idea what is wrong with the above arguement ...$\ddot \smile$

Comment: Thanks, Donald.  This one has been keeping me up at night for the last week.  I am very interested in finding the problem.  :-)

Comment: @LarryFreeman, you might want to try posting this question to [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net), to see what the number theory experts there would say...

Comment: Thanks @Jose for the suggestion! I have posted a [question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/271628/15915) on mo related to the Heilbronn-Rohrbach Inequality which will hopefully provide insights on the validity of Claim 2.

Comment: what does "too elementary to be true" mean? Is $2+2=4$ too elementary to be true? Do you have a specific $a$ and $n$ that provide a counterexample?

Comment: I mean no disrespect to mathematicians more talented than I (such as Paul Erdos) who used elementary methods to advance mathematics.  It usually takes a new idea to breakthrough to new advances.  An argument from an amateur (such as myself0 that is elementary and attempts to break new ground is usually mistaken.  My goal here is to learn from my mistakes (including the possibility of being mistaken about a proof being wrong).

Comment: I have written a c# program that draws a bar chart of the number of primes in the intervals & this suggest the result is true & a value of considerably smaller than $128$ will work. I am slightly over whelmed by your questions & don't really know where to start ... 
2318255/counting-the-number-of-integers-i-where-i-le-x-and-gcdx-p-1
... I could write an answer to this, with some screen shots of the afore mentioned bar charts, this would give numerical evidence supporting your conjecture, but would be way short of a proof or an adequate answer to your question.

Comment: If you summarize your results as an answer, I will be very glad to accept.  I am working on a full proof and would be glad to see the results of your investigation.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer falls short of what might be considered an adequate response, but does offer good evidence for the veracity of what is stated in the question.

The assertion : There is at least $1$ prime in the interval $(an,(a+1)n]$ for $1 \leq a \leq n $ & $n \geq 2$ , is true (IMO).

Given a value of $n$, how many primes are there between $n$ and $2n$ ? Of course Bertrands postulate states that there is at least one. Classic proofs of this are given by Ramanujan & Erdos, they are closely related to original proof given by Chebyshev.

How many primes are there between $ 2n $ & $3n$ or $3n$ or $4n$ or $\cdots$ or $an$ & $(a+1)n$ ?

The following bar chart shows how many are primes are in each interval for the value $n=6$ (The red line indicates a frequency of three). This pictorially represents that the intervals $[1,6],[7,12],[13,18],[19,24],[25,30],[31,36],[37,42]$ contain $3,2,2,2,1,1,2$ primes respectively.
[image]

Numerical experimentation certainly suggests the answer there is at least one prime in each interval $(an,(a+1)n]$ for $1 \leq a \leq n $ & $n \geq 2$. So (we believe) the major claim of the question is true & the restriction $ n \geq 128$ can be relaxed to $ n \geq 2$.

We shall now look more closely at assertion (2). Firstly we shall tighten, the constraint that the values are coprime to the "quarter primorial", to require the values to be prime.

So we are interested in the question: When do all the intervals $(an,(a+1)n]$ contain at least $3$ primes ?

For "small" values of $n$ the assertion is of course negative. The first value when this phenomena occurs is when $n=26$.
[image]

It also fails for the n-values  $27,30,31,37,38,39,\color{red}{40}$.
[image]

So (we believe) a slightly modified version of assertion (2) is ture for $n \geq 41$.

We include the graph for $n=128$ as this value lowest limit used in the question.
[image]